# V-if not reactive in Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button that I'm rendering with a Vue component. The button depends on some `async` data from the backend that controls its visibility. The data is being returned and updated fine. However, the button is not shown for some reason. I'm not sure if its because the DOM has already loaded? Not sure why I'm not seeing the button. I've tried both using a computed property as well as a simple data property and both don't work.

However, the `console.log` IS showing the correct data at the correct time.

Plus if I just set `displayLauncherButton` it displays fine.

EDIT:
To clarify this is a component that gets inserted into an HTML document that was rendered with liquid.

Here is my simplified code:

```
Vue.component('fresh-credit', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      creditAmount: '',
      currencySymbol: '',
      customerId: '',
      displayLauncherButton: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCustomerCredit
    this.makeItShow
  },
  template: 
    `
    <div :style="buttonContainer" v-if="makeItShow">
      <button 
        :style="buttonStyle"
        >You Have $</button>
    </div>
    `,
  computed: {
    makeItShow() {
      console.log("this is returning " + this.displayLauncherButton)
      return this.displayLauncherButton
    },
    buttonContainer() {
      return {
        position: 'fixed',
        right: '10px',
        top: '150px',
        zIndex: '99999',
      }
    },
    buttonStyle() {
      return {
        'border-radius': '4px',
        'border': 'none',
        'height': '44px',
        'min-width': '78px',
        'padding': '0 19.5555555556px',
        'font-size': '14px',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'text-transform': 'uppercase',
        'cursor': 'pointer',
        'color': 'white',
        'background-color': '#4D4D4DFF',
        'box-shadow': '0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12)!important',
        'outline': 'none',
      }
    },
    async getCustomerCredit() {
      if(this.customerId) {
        let response = await axios.post(`/apps/fresh_credit_proxy`, { shopify_customer_id: this.customerId, type: 'customer_credit'})
        if(response.status == 200) {
          if(response.data.customer_credit == 'no_credit') {
            this.displayLauncherButton = false
            return 
          }
          else {
            this.creditAmount = response.data.customer_credit.current_credit_balance
            this.currencySymbol = response.data.customer_credit.current_credit_balance
            this.displayLauncherButton = true
            console.log("during get credit " + this.displayLauncherButton)
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
})

new Vue({ el: '#freshie' })
```

Comment: This should work if you set makeItShow() under methods instead. I don't think computed can be triggered in mounted().

Comment: By the way, all those functions should be moved to methods (), they are not typical computed properties.

Comment: `getCustomerCredit()` should definitely be a method. And note the Options API does not support async computed props (but there are third party libs that implement a workaround).

Comment: Hmm, I use these computed properties as watchers in essence. So that when a element in the computed property changes, it re-runs. The thing is, the data is updated regardless of computed or method. However, this component is inside an HTML DOM.. But either way computer or method, the button is still not showing.. its weird

Comment: @tony, had no idea `async` getters are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

`computed` are getters.

This means that

```
mounted() {
  this.getCustomerCredit
  this.makeItShow
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
mounted() {
  this.getCustomerCredit
  false
}
```

... because `makeItShow` gets the current value of `displayLauncherButton`, which is `false` in `mounted`.

You probably want:

```
mounted() {
  this.getCustomerCredit().then(() => {
    console.log(this.makeItShow);
  });
}, 
methods: {
  // move if here from getters
  async getCustomerCredit() {
    /.../
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need `makeItShow` at all. It will always return the current value of `displayLauncherButton`, so you can just use `displayLauncherButton` instead.

If you want to run some effect whenever `displayLauncherButton` changes, don't use a `computed`, use a watch on `displayLauncherButton`. For example, to log the value of `displayLauncherButton` every time it changes, add:

```
watch: {
  displayLauncherButton: console.log
}
```

to your component. This will log both parameters `(newVal, oldVal)`, every time it changes.

---

Note the `mounted` above can also be written as:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getCustomerCredit();
  console.log(this.makeItShow)
}
```

Don't let `async mounted` trick you into believing it will delay the rendering of the component. The component will render before `mounted` returns if `mounted` is `async`.